# SQL to find rows with selected property values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database view which gives me following result:
[image]

From this I want to select all the users which have groups 00113 and 00221.. so on. That is the users which have access to all those groups and not any one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a fan of using `group by` and `having` for these types of queries.  One method for finding things in a list:

```
select id
from table
where group_number in ('00113', '00221')
group by id
having count(distinct group_number = '00113') = 2;
```

A more general method that allows you to get members of one list, excluding members from another:

```
select id
from table
group by id
having sum(case when group_number = '00113' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when group_number = '00221' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Your first query is exactly what i was trying to explain to @maandoo in the comments. That should be what OP wants. It would be easier to add a list of group_numbers in the first query in my opinion, although both do the same thing. Also you might want to check the COUNT function and take the `= '00113'` out.

Comment: @jpw . . . Name the table in the `from` clause:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57a88/13.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 
where ID not IN 
( select distinct ID from Table
   where GROUP_NUMBER not IN ('00221','00113') 
) group by ID having count (distinct GROUP_NUMBER) = 2;
```

As ruudvan pointed out this can be directly done with only one  `IN`

```
 select * from table 
 where ID IN ('00221','00113') 
 group by ID having count (distinct GROUP_NUMBER) = 2;
```

The inner query gives the list of all IDs whose group_number is not present in the given list.
So you need to select all the IDs not present in the IDs given by inner query

Comment: What about IDs that only have any 1 of the group_numbers from the list and not all? If i understand correctly, OP wants IDs which have all the groups in the list.

Comment: Why not simply "where GROUP_NUMBER not IN ('00113', '00221')" in the sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh I knew that would work but  tried it in my terminal and didn't work so just edited it this way...  Does that work ?

Comment: @jarlh My bad.. I wrote a wrong query while testing... It works

Comment: Note that `count (GROUP_NUMBER) = 2` will change to 3 or 4 and so on ... based on the number of elements in the list.

Comment: @ruudvan Yeah that's obvious... whenever the OP wants to add he needs to add it in the above list and change the count also.... I feel there should be better ways to solve this

Comment: Also, he can't do a SELECT *, but select ID

Comment: @ruudvan Why  can't he do that ?

Comment: Yes there is a better way. I was thinking of adding it to my answer but you can do it instead. Instead of doing a NOT IN twice, you can just do a `IN (list)` and then group by ID having `count(distinct group_number) = N`. This way you would use the index on group_number column.

Comment: `SELECT ID` only because `group by ID`.

Comment: You have to do a count(distinct group_number) though because there could be multiple rows with the same group_number. Not sure of OPs data. Also, `SELECT ID` only.

Comment: When you do a group by on a column, you can only select that column and any aggregates on other columns.

Comment: @ruudvan Nope that's not correct... You need to only take care that you select the  column on which you are grouping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74566/discussion-between-ruudvan-and-maandoo).

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is a bit ambiguous but if what you want is to return the user that for example have access to the groups `00113` and `00221` and no other groups then this would work.

One way to do this would be to use a conditional aggregation in the having clause of the group by:

```
select id from your_table
group by id
having sum(case 
    when group_number = '00113' then 1
    when group_number = '00221' then 1 
    else -1 end
    ) = 2
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57a88/5)

Answer (score -1):

```
select first_name, last_name, id from mytable where group_number = '00113'
INTERSECT
select first_name, last_name, id from mytable where group_number = '00221'
```

Comment: The question asks for users that have _access to all those groups and not any one group._ This query would not exclude those users that have access to more groups.

Comment: You might be right. The problem statement is ambiguous. I didn't interpret the statement as saying that it needs to have access to only these two groups and not any other groups. The way it is right now, it only says that the ID should have ALL these groups and not just SOME of them. Nothing about having other groups along with ALL of the ones in list.

Comment: Ah, you're right - it's ambiguous. I read it as "only those groups" but it might be "those and any other"